# Scala Map[Regex, String] collectFirst error

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to automatically convert a string to Date based on regex matches. My code thus far is as below:

```
package be.folks.date

import java.util.Date
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

class StringToDate(underlying:String) {

  val regmap : Map[Regex, String] = Map(
    ("""\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d""".r, "dd-MM-yyyy"),
    ("""\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d""".r, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
  )

  def toDate() : Date = { 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern((regmap collectFirst { case (_(underlying) , v) => v  } get)).parseDateTime(underlying).toDate()
  }

}

object StringToDate {
  implicit def +(s:String) = new StringToDate(s)
}
```

However, I am getting an error for "_" - ) expected but found (.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your syntax to apply the Regex. Maybe, in `toDate`, you wanted:

```
regmap collectFirst {
    case (pattern , v)  if((pattern findFirstIn underlying).nonEmpty) => v}
```

I also would not use `get` to extract the string from the option, as it throws an exception if no matching regex is found. I don't know how you want to manage that case in your code so I can't give you suggestions.

Comment: I am going to leave it at exception for get :)